# Multiple css rules for an html node

Tags: html, css, attributes

Can someone please help me with the css syntax for having multiple css rules for an html node with data attributes.

Here is some code that does work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div class='Css_Rule_red Css_Rule_size'>
    Test text
</div>

<style>.Css_Rule_red {
    color: red;
}
.Css_Rule_size {
    font-size: 500px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div data-custom-css='Css_Rule_red Css_Rule_size'>
    Test text
</div>

<style>[data-custom-css='Css_Rule_red'] {
    color: red;
}
[data-custom-css='Css_Rule_size'] {
    font-size: 500px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Both the `'Css_Rule_red'` and `'Css_Rule_size'` work individually, however, the above code does not display either of the `'Css_Rule_red'` or `'Css_Rule_size'` css rules when combined together.

How is it possible to have multiple css rules, when using data attributes?

Answer (score 1):

https://amcss.github.io/

More info about Attribute selectors - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```
[data-custom-css~="Css_Rule_red"] {
  color: red;
}

[data-custom-css~="Css_Rule_size"] {
  font-size: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this :

```
    .Css_Rule_red {
        color: red;
    font-size: 500px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `data-custom-css` is a separate tag than `class`, and you should use `[data-custom-css='Css_Rule_red Css_Rule_size']`..

```
<style>
[data-custom-css='Css_Rule_red Css_Rule_size']
{
    color: red;
    font-size: 500px;
}
</style>
```

or

```
<div data-custom-css='Css_Rule_red' data-custom-css2='Css_Rule_size'>
    Test text
</div>

<style>[data-custom-css='Css_Rule_red'] {
    color: red;
}
[data-custom-css2='Css_Rule_size'] {
    font-size: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use different data attributes for each data entry.
With data attributes it's the same as with IDs. if you use multiple, none of them will work. If you want to have both of the classes as data attributes you could set them like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div data-custom-css-colour='Css_Rule_red' data-custom-css-size='Css_Rule_size'>
    Test text
</div>

<style>
  [data-custom-css-colour='Css_Rule_red'] {
    color: red;
  }
  [data-custom-css-size='Css_Rule_size'] {
    font-size: 500px;
  }
</style>
</html>
```